# Using material design colors inside my custom view onDraw method

Tags: android, material-design, ondraw

I'm trying to wrap my head around using the colors in a material design app. I have a custom view which does some things in its onDraw method, and I would like to use the colors available to the app and be consistent with material design. But, how do I access primary, secondary, font (etc.) colors inside my java code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you programmatically access colors (defined in colors.xml)

```
private int getColor(int colorAttr) {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[] { colorAttr });
    int color = a.getColor(0, 0);
    a.recycle();
    return color;
}

//examples accessing colors
int colorAccent = getColor(R.attr.colorAccent);
int colorPrimary = getColor(R.attr.colorPrimary);
```

Comment: So, is this the same as choosing a theme (say dark) and then using this code to retrieve the primary and secondary colors? I've not defined anything in colors XML file. Is there a missing step?

Comment: Well, to stay consistent with how you are supposed to define the color palette for material design within your apps, you do need to define colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark, colorAccent. Do this in colors.xml (might need to make this in the values folder). Right now, it will be accessing the primary color defined by the theme you are using. So if you haven't defined them explicitly, it just grabs whatever is the default of that theme (I am pretty sure).